# html tags from xml using libxml

Tags: html, xml, perl, libxml2

i have a xml like this

```
 <text>
        <h1>First title</h1>
        <p>First paragraph</p>
        <p>Second paragraph</p>
 </text>
```

and a perl script

```
my $file = '../data/text.xml';
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($file);
my $root= $doc->getDocumentElement;
$t=$doc->findnodes("//text")->get_node(1);
$text=encode_entities($t->findvalue('text'));
```

The problem is that when i'm printing the text, perl ignores those 2 html tags and returns only

> "First title First paragraph Second paragraph"

Then the page content is not correct. What can I do? Is there a way without cycling and taking each paragraph manually? The xml could have a title and a paragraph, 20 paragraphs or even a paragraph, a title, another paragraph and a smaller title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
join q(), map { $_->toString } $doc->findnodes("//text")->get_node(1)->childNodes
```